# Adding hours to the current time in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to add 4 hours to the current hour, only the hour, not minutes. Is that possible?
In my program I am using:

```
hour = current_time.hour
```

If I just add 4 to the hour, if the time is 22 for example, I will get 26. Can someone help me?

Comment: What does this have to do with `selenium`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a full date-time, you can use the `timedelta` object:

```
time_in_four_hours = current_time + timedelta(hours=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on the modulo operator.

The code `hour = (current_time.hour + 4) % 24` will do exactly what you want.